# Oracle 10g range partition with interval as 1 month

Tags: oracle10g

I want to partition a txn table with range partition with 1 month interval in 10g. Table having txn_date.

I want the partition to be automatic. 
I think this is possible in 11 but is there any way to achieve in 10g.

```
create table part
(
   txn_Date date
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (txn_date)
INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'))
(
   partition p1 values less than (TO_DATE('01-NOV-2007','DD-MON-YYYY'))
);
```

Comment: The question and the answer both make assumptions about the date format or language.  I strongly recommend you always use ANSI date literals, such as `date '2007-11-01'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could schedule a job to add these partitions as and when appropriate. Since this is a DDL, this would be done using Dynamic SQL.

Eg. For a table that holds data partitioned by month, you could have a job on the last weekend of each month which creates the parititons for next month.

```
create or replace procedure p_part_maintenance_mnthy
as
declare
  v_partition_name all_tab_partitions.partition_name%type;
  v_limit varchar2(50);
begin

  select to_char(trunc(add_months(sysdate,1),'MM'),'MonYYYY')
    into v_partition_name 
    from dual; --eg. output Oct2012

  select to_char(trunc(add_months(sysdate,2),'MM'),'dd-mon-yyyy')
    into v_limit
    from dual; -- eg. output 01-nov-2012

execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE sales ADD PARTITION ' || v_partition_name ||
                   ' VALUES LESS THAN (' || v_limit || ') tablespace XYZ';

end;
/
```

Typically all similar function calls such as above (daily, monthly and yearly) would be in one package and take in the table_name as input as well. These are called from individual procedures as necessary.